# Checking duplicate files against a dictionary of filesizes and names

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

This is pretty simple code - i've just completed Charles Severances Python for Informatics course, so if possible pls help me to keep it simple.

I'm trying to find duplicate documents in folders.
What i'm having trouble with is printing out the original, and the duplicate so i can manually check the accuracy of what it found.  Later i'll look at how to automate deleting duplicates, looking for other filetypes etc.

A similarly structured piece of code worked well for itunes, but here i'm putting originals into a dictionary, and it seems i'm not getting the info back out.

Pls keep it simple, so i can learn. I know i can copy code to do the job, but i'm more interested in learning where i've gone wrong.

cheers
jeff

```
import os
from os.path import join
import re
import hashlib
location = '/Users/jeff/desktop/typflashdrive'
doccount = 0
dupdoc = 0

d = dict()

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(location):
    for x in files:
        size = hashlib.md5(x).hexdigest()
        item = os.path.join(dirname,x)
        #print os.path.getsize(item), item

        #size = os.path.getsize(item)

        if item.endswith ('.doc'):
            doccount = doccount + 1
            if size not in d:
                original = item
                d[size] = original
            else:
                copy = item
                for key in d: print key, d[size],'\n', size, copy,'\n','\n',
                #print item,'\n', copy,'\n','\n',
                dupdoc=dupdoc+1
print '.doc Files:', doccount,'.', 'You have', dupdoc, 'duplicate .doc files:',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest mistake is that you're taking the hash of the filenames instead of the file content.

I have corrected that and also cleaned up the rest of the code:

```
import os
import hashlib


location = '/Users/jeff/desktop/typflashdrive'
doc_count = 0
dup_doc_count = 0

hash_vs_file = {}

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(location):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        file_hash = hashlib.md5(open(file_path).read()).hexdigest()
        if filename.endswith('.doc'):
            doc_count = doc_count + 1
            if file_hash not in hash_vs_file:
                hash_vs_file[file_hash] = [file_path]
            else:
                dup_doc_count += 1
                hash_vs_file[file_hash].append(file_path)

print 'doc_count = ', doc_count
print 'dup_doc_count = ', dup_doc_count

for file_hash in hash_vs_file:
    print file_hash
    for file_path in hash_vs_file[file_hash]:
        print file_path
    print "\n\n\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll go through it and see how your edits have changed it.  Appreciate very much the effort you made for me.!

Comment: Hi, example output below.  How can i print the originally recorded filepath in the ouput so i can manually compare the potential duplicates.   Not sure why obviously different files are having same file-hash - coincidence?
969e5db7bd3d616f9e1d614dcfb73bf7
/Users/jeff/desktop/typflashdrive/Activity Program No Golf/May05/~$ Creation Schedule Cultural (May05).doc
/Users/jeff/desktop/typflashdrive/Activity Program No Golf/May05/~$-creation Schedule for Spouses.doc
/Users/jeff/desktop/typflashdrive/Activity Program No Golf/May05/~$ge 1 welcome about this guide doc.doc

Comment: The first file in the output is the *original* one I guess.

Comment: Hi @anmol. Ok figured out whats confused me.  the last files that recorded were all temp files with ~$.....   so all a few kb, so coincidentally i guess had the same hash values.   higher up the list are all duplicate named files (where more than one entry occurs).  So is it that instead of a dictionary with key/value pairs we've now created tuples with many possible filenames in it?

Comment: Hi @Jeffnewy. Actually, its a dictionary with hash as the key and the list of the paths of the file with that hash as the value.

Comment: thanks for your help.  i've hit the next hurdle, and posted it as a new question, rather than continue to bother you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36373343/5893713 Nice profile pic btw.