# filter list of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary called `hash_vs_file`
keys are `file_hash`
values are `file_path` (a list of one or more filepaths)

I want to isolate and print only the items where the list is longer than one filepath.

I'm trying, without result:

```
for file_hash in hash_vs_file:
    if len(file_path) > 1 in hash_vs_file.items():   
        print file_hash
        print file_path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) this way instead:

```
for file_hash, file_path in hash_vs_file.iteritems():
    if len(file_path) > 1:   
        print file_path
        print file_hash
```

Because the way you did, you are getting only  the keys of the dictionary so  checking the length of `file_path` fails.

**Update:**

You asked for the readability of the output.
You can inspire yourself from this method:

```
print file_path, file_hash
```

Or this better one which relies on [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "File Path: {} ------ File Hash: {}".format(file_path,file_hash)
```

Or, if you want it to look like a list, try this instead:

```
print "[{}, {}]".format(file_path,file_hash)
```

Comment: Legend.  that did the trick, and at a level of complexity i can understand!.   One follow up question, when i wasn't trying to filter by length, and just used **for file_hash in hash_vs_file:**  it would print the hash_file on one line, and each file_path on a separate line.  Now all the values run together as a list.  is there a simple way to split those back onto separate lines for readability?

Answer (score 0):

```
for file_hash, file_path in hash_vs_file.items():
    if len(file_path) > 1:   
        print file_hash
        print file_path
```

The method `.items()` gives you a tuple of key and value.
You can unpack this tuple with `file_hash, file_path`, so that 
you have access to each `file_hash` and `file_path` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) built in function to return an iterator like so:

```
for file_hash in filter(lambda key: len(hash_vs_file[key]) > 1, hash_vs_file):
    print("{} : {}".format(file_hash, hash_vs_file[file_hash]))
```

Or you can use [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for a newly filtered dictionary:

```
hash_vs_file = {fhash: fpath for fhash, fpath in hash_vs_file.items() if len(fpath) > 1}
print(hash_vs_file)
```