# Delete folders and sub folders sharing the same name using python 2.7 - Error

Tags: python-2.7, directory, subdirectory

I try to delete a duplicated folders that sharing the same folder's name.

All the folders spread in one big folder that divided into a lot of subfolders and sub subfolders. In each subfolder the is files- it doesn't matter the name of the files and if those files also duplicated in the other folders. I don't care of the folder content. All i need is to check duplicated name folder- and if there is- the code will delete the duplicated folder.
I try to write this code:

```
import os,sys,fnmatch,shutil

path = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\ab"
groups_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirs:
        groups_list.append(name)
        print name, 'appears', groups_list.count(name), 'times'
        if groups_list.count(name) >= 2: # if there are 2 or more duplictes
            print name
            shutil.rmtree(path)
```

I get an error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] : 'G:\\desktop\\Project\\lyr\\ab\\6105\\5001184\\5001184.jpg'
```

> > > 

The order of the folders and subfolders is:

[image]

In folders 6105 and 6195 there folder with the same name:5001225. that folder i want to delete.

For the example i showed little example. In real, directory ab as several of duplicated sub folders.

I red [Checking duplicate files against a dictionary of filesizes and names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233261/checking-duplicate-files-against-a-dictionary-of-filesizes-and-names) and there no answer to my problem  because i need to delete the whole duplicated folder and also, i don't care of the size\name of the files inside the folders and subfolders.

Comment: This help http://code.activestate.com/recipes/364953-find-duplicate-file-names/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking duplicate files against a dictionary of filesizes and names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233261/checking-duplicate-files-against-a-dictionary-of-filesizes-and-names)

Comment: i edged my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me finally:

```
import os,sys,fnmatch,shutil

root = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\ab"
groups_list = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        groups_list.append(subdirname)
        if groups_list.count(subdirname) >= 2: # if there are 2 or more duplictes
            dir_to_delete = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            print subdirname, 'appears', groups_list.count(subdirname), 'times'
            print dir_to_delete
            shutil.rmtree(dir_to_delete)
```